# How to return this JavaScript result in a PHP file in Magento?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, magento

I know the PHP works on the backend side and JavaScript works on the Client side, but it does makes me confuse when I customize the Magento function.

I have a line of code to recalculate my price in **Product.js** which looks like:

```
document.getElementById("finalprice").innerHTML = '$' + fomattedprice ;
var priceToDisplay = document.getElementById("finalprice").innerHTML = '$' + fomattedprice ;
```

I know this is some duplicate codes above but since i want to make life easier, i store my answer into another variable call priceToDisplay. And now I want to return my priceToDisplay like this in **Data.php**:

`public function formatPrice($price)
    { return $this->getQuote()->getStore()->formatPrice(priceToDisplay);}`

This doesn't make any sense since the path is not even on the right track, therefore I have tried something else which make more sense:

```
  public function formatPrice($price)
{
    return $_GET['priceToDisplay'];
}
```

Now it make more sense yes? But it doesn't work still, is it not able to pass the javascirpt value to the **Data.php**?

I can put more detail if required. Thank you very much :)

*P.S:* I had included the **Product.js** in the **page.xml** and tested it with an alert box, so i am 100% sure the **Data.php** is linked with  **Product.js**.

**UPDATE 1:** I found out that my var is empty by using `console.log(priceToDisplay);` to test it. It display the number in the **view.phtml** page but nothing on the **Data.php** page.

**UPDATE 2:** Let's make things easier, I have the price reloader function to calculate the price when custom options been changed in Product.js, then pass the recalculated price to the product page
[image]

i just want the shopping cart return the same result because it is not now.
[image]